# table class in php

Tags: php, css

Is it possible to put a table class in php, like this:

```
echo "<table  class='xd' border='1'>
<tr>
<th>IDNO</th>
<th>ADDRESS</th>
<th>LASTNAME</th>
<th>FIRSTNAME</th>

</tr>";
```

I have a table inside a table. The outside table is html. And if I only put table in the css. It will affect both. But when I put class in the table with php script. It won't work. Please help.

Comment: *What* "won't work"? Is the class not output into the source code? Is it not accepted by the browser? Have you checked with a tool like Firebug how the element appears in  the DOM? Won't CSS apply to it?

Comment: PHP is irrelevant here. The browser only sees whatever HTML and CSS you send.

Comment: Just a thought, use " instead of ' when calling classes.

Comment: a table inside a table is ... well... wrong in most cases. Not that it doesn't work, it just doesn't respond to styling very well and it (the code) looks ugly. Consider taking a deeper insight into CSS (http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/), you'd be amazed of what you can accomplish in much less time, and how simple does the page look afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will effect all tables on the page:

```
table {
}
```

Affects just tables with the class bla:

```
table.bla {
}
```

Comment: I guess it will be easier if you paste the sourcecode (from the browser when the page has loaded) on a paste site like http://pastebin.com/.

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can do so. if your css doesn't work, maybe your selector is wrong? (mixed up #bla and .bla ?)